# Why cant login to couchbase?

Tags: couchbase

I'm new with couchbase, and i install it with `dpkg -i couchbase-version` but when i go to `localhost:8091`, I can't settings or something like that,  just the login screen and about, i can not set up cluster or server or anything.

Is there a default user-password pair?

I Tried the followings:

```
admin-admin,root-root but i cant login.
```

What can be a problem, can anyone helps to me? Thanks a lot.

Ohh, and im using jessie debian 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you sure there wasn't a previous install of couchbase on that machine?

maybe that previous version was uninstalled via `dpkg`, but the data files weren't deleted? on Debian they should be under `opt/couchbase`... See the [doc](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.1/install/install-uninstalling.html#story-h2-2) on uninstalling on Debian.

If they're still here, you could follow the steps in the link above. For the last paragrap about data files, you'd need to delete the `opt/couchbase/` folder. Then reinstall and you should be able to do the setup.

**ONLY DO THAT IF you're positive losing the data isn't a problem** of course (eg. dev machine).

Comment: Thanks a lot....i not removed the /op/couchbase....but i newly created this couchbase...i never use it...until now...doesnt matter now works, thanks a lot :)